# '(NSObject, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: string, dictionary, swift, nsstring, option-type

How do I convert an object of type `(NSObject, AnyObject)` to the type `String`?

At the end of the first line of the method below, `as String` causes the compiler error:

```
'(NSObject, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'String'
```

Casting `street` to `NSString` instead of `String` compiles, but I'm casting `street` to `String` because I want to compare it to `placemark.name`, which has the type `String!`, not `NSString`.

I know `name` and `street` are optionals, but I'm assuming they're not `nil` for now because all the places returned from `MKLocalSearch` seem to have non-nil names and streets.

```
func formatPlacemark(placemark: CLPlacemark) -> (String, String) {
    let street = placemark.addressDictionary["Street"] as String
    if placemark.name == street {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `String` is not an object, so you do need to cast it to an `NSString`.  I would recommend the following syntax to cast it and unwrap it at the same time.  Don't worry about comparing it to a variable of type `String!` since they are compatible.  This will work:

```
func formatPlacemark(placemark: CLPlacemark) -> (String, String) {
    if let street = placemark.addressDictionary["Street"] as? NSString {
        if placemark.name == street {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

This has the added benefits that if "Street" is not a valid key in your dictionary or if the object type is something other than `NSString`, this will not crash.  It just won't enter the block.

If you **really** want street to be a `String` you could do this:

```
if let street:String = placemark.addressDictionary["Street"] as? NSString
```

but it doesn't buy you anything in this case.

Comment: How do you know I can do `placemark.name == street` instead of `street.isEqualToString(placemark.name)`? I want to make sure I'm checking for string equality (`isEqualToString`), not object identity (`==`).

Comment: Swift automatically bridges between the two types, and `==` is the Swift way of testing string equality.  See: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Comment: Try this in a Playground:var a:NSString = "abcdefg"
var b:String = "abc" + "defg"
if a == b {
    println("yep they're the same")
}

Answer (score 2):

The return type from looking up via subscript for a swift dictionary has to be an optional since there may be no value for the given key.

Therefor you must do:

```
as String?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may have to do with `addressDictionary` being an `NSDictionary`.

If you convert `addressDictionary` to a Swift dictionary, it should work.

```
let street = (placemark.addressDictionary as Dictionary<String, String>)["String"]
```

Comment: But, is this slower than [@vacawama's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25582668/242933)? Because isn't `Dictionary` completely different than `NSDictionary`? So, would that mean by casting the `NSDictionary` to `Dictionary`, the program will have to create a completely new `Dictionary` object and fill it with the keys & values of the original `NSDictionary`? That sounds like more work than just a simple cast.

Comment: This isn't safe.  If any value in the dictionary is an object other than an `NSString`, this will crash the app.  You'd only do this if you were 100% sure all of the objects were `NSString`s, and then you'd do it only once, when the data is first created.  If you are calling an API external to your app to get the `NSDictionary`, it would be safer to check each object with the optional form of the type cast operator (`as?`).