# Cannot convert the type [NSObject : AnyObject] to string

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code in Swift using Xcode 7.2 ..

```
func silentPostData(serverName: String, serverport serverPort: String, serverurl serverURL: String, parameters: [NSObject : AnyObject], urldata urlData: NSData) {
    let persist = Persistence()
    var finalURl = "https://\(serverName):\(serverPort)/\(serverURL)"
    for key : String in parameters  {
        finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString(key)
        finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString("=")
       finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString((parameters[key] as! String))
        finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString("&")
    }
}
```

I get an error(mentioned as the title) in the line "for key : String in parameters {" . Based on the previous answer ['(NSObject, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579183/nsobject-anyobject-is-not-convertible-to-string) , i tried casting it to NSString , but it didn't work.So Anyone knows how to convert [NSObject:AnyObject] to string ? Thank You in advance.

Comment: It's not possible to convert a dictionary into a string.

Comment: But it works in my Objective C code..

Comment: - (void) silentPostData :(NSString*) serverName serverport:(NSString*)serverPort serverurl:(NSString*)serverURL parameters:(NSMutableDictionary*)parameters urldata:(NSData*)urlData {
    
    Persistence *persist = [[Persistence alloc]init];
    NSString *finalURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@/%@?", serverName, serverPort, serverURL];

Comment: for(NSString *key in parameters) {
        finalURL = [finalURL stringByAppendingString:key];
        finalURL = [finalURL stringByAppendingString:@"="];
        finalURL = [finalURL stringByAppendingString:[parameters objectForKey:key]];
        finalURL = [finalURL stringByAppendingString:@"&"];

Comment: I'm sorry for the format of the code in comments though :)

Comment: You can just edit your own question instead of pasting the unreadable code in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments said, it's a dictionary and you could get the strings by doing this:

```
parameters.keys.flatMap { $0 as? String }.forEach {
    finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString($0)
    finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString("=")
    finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString(parameters[$0] as? String ?? "")
    finalURL = finalURL.stringByAppendingString("&")
}
```

Comment: I have another doubt , can you answer it here ?

Comment: Sure, you can edit your question or make a new question.

Comment: I ain't able to post that question as I can post once in every 90 minutes.. however i will send u the link asap